# Strange git branch showing up in all my repos

Tags: git, security

I noticed that any git repo that I create or clone has a `—quiet` branch in it,
I cannot check it out or do anything with it and I don't know where it comes from,
Any ideas?

I regularly use github, source tree (mac version), git command line,

Any suggestions is appreciated,

**EDIT2:**
as noted by @DCoder the first character is not a regular hyphen or minus sign, which makes it even more suspicious,

**EDIT:**
If I do `git branch`
I get:

```
 * ali
  master
  —quiet
```

if I then do `git checkout -quit` or `git checkout "-quit"` or `git checkout \-quit` or `git checkout -- --quit` or anyother variant that come to mind I get:

```
 error: pathspec '-quiet' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I looked into my `~/.gitconfig` file and did not find anything that could be related to this,

Comment: The `git clone` command comes with a `--quiet` option, are you somehow passing that as an argument where it shouldn't be?

Comment: Have you tried checking it out with `git checkout -- --quiet`? Probably some tool or script is using the `--quiet` option the wrong way.

Comment: could be, but I have not yet been able to find it, any suggestions where to look?

Comment: That's not a typical hyphen at the beginning of the branch name, it's an *m-dash*. Copy-paste it into the `git checkout` command instead of typing a hyphen.

Comment: @DCoder you are absolutely correct, I can check it out with `—quiet` which is not `-quiet` let me investigate more

Comment: Just take a look at the filename at `.git/refs/heads/*`, it contains the sha-1. You can also just delete it.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann but I really want to know where it is coming from

Comment: @Ali The date of the file might be useful in your quest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit,
I should have guessed it,
A few days back, I copied and pasted a config script from a webpage to my fish config file,
And as it happens in addition to ' and " that where replaced by similar looking characters - was also replaced but I had missed it,

Thanks to @DCoder I did a `grep` on everything and found it in my fish config file,

Case closed,